# Get the element closer to the middle of the screen in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of item divs in the page.

example:

```
<div data-page='1' class'item' ></div>
<div data-page='1' class'item' ></div>
<div data-page='1' class'item' ></div>
<div data-page='2' class'item' ></div>
<div data-page='2' class'item' ></div>
<div data-page='2' class'item' ></div>
<div data-page='3' class'item' ></div>
<div data-page='3' class'item' ></div>
<div data-page='3' class'item' ></div>
```

I need to find out the element that is in the most center part of the screen and get its `data-page` number.

If all the div are close to the button of the page or not visible because its down the page, I get the top most one because it's closer to the middle, and if all the div are above the middle or not visible because they are at the upper part of the window outside the visible view, I get the bottom most div because it's closer to the middle.

What I've tried ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301961/add-a-class-to-the-image-closest-to-the-center-of-the-viewport)):

```
$(".item").sort(function(a,b){
      return Math.abs(1 - (($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()/2-$(a).height()/2) / $(a).position().top)) - 
             Math.abs(1 - (($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()/2-$(b).height()/2) / $(b).position().top))
    })[0].css("background", "red");
```

The above function didn't work for me, because it highlighted in red a bottom most element.

How can I do that in jQuery and also continuously report the closest one as I vertically scroll the page.

Comment: Can you please explain more ?

Comment: @SunilKumar There are DIVs arranged one of top of the other vertically. I want to get the element that is in the most middle part of the screen.

Comment: you can try this link https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/2L92c7ww/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the scroll event, you can get the middle of the sreen and then loop the elements you want to check and get each of their positions and find which is closest to the middle of the screen

```
 $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){        
        // get the scroll position of the document + half the window height
        var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() / 2);
        var positions = [];

        // push each of the items we want to check against to an array with their position and selector
        $('.item').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            positions.push({position:$(this).position().top, element: $(this)});
        });

        var getClosest = closest(positions,scrollTop);
        getClosest.addClass("active"); // the element closest to the middle of the screen
        console.log( getClosest.attr("data-page") );
    });

    // finds the nearest position (from an array of objects) to the specified number
    function closest(array, number) {
        var num = 0;
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(Math.abs(number - array[i].position) < Math.abs(number - array[num].position)){
                num = i;
            }
        }
        return array[num].element;
    }        
});
```

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/fa90a23u/)

Comment: Your code doen't work exactly. When you scrolled to bottom, it has fault.

Comment: It shows me only the bottom element in red. Have no idea why.

Comment: For example when page scrolled to `15px` it doesn't select correct element. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fa90a23u/2/).

Comment: @Mohammad Weird, your example works fine for me... Chrome on Windows. The one thing it's not taking into account is the height of the elements. Currently it's calculating based on the top position of them. I'll wait for feedback from OP and help him calculate the offset based on the height if needed

Comment: Why does it put the class on the parent when I am in the exact middle? UPDATE. it's not the exact middle, its like every odd step of the mouse wheel, it puts the active class on the parent.

Comment: I need to also take the middle of the element into consideration (element height / 2) .But please check my other comment above.

Comment: Let's go to chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118209/38564630

Comment: That problem was that you calculate the position relative to the container, and I need relative to the window/screen. Changed that and it works!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `document.elementFromPoint` giving it the x and y coordinates of the middle of the screen

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  let x = window.innerWidth / 2;
  let y = window.innerHeight / 2;
  let element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  let page = element.getAttribute("data-page");
  document.querySelector(".middle") &&   document.querySelector(".middle").classList.remove("middle");
  element.classList.add("middle"); 
})
```

read more about [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

here is a [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOjjRg)

Comment: This has problem, when It's in the exact middle it puts the class on the parent (?!), and if the items are out of bound, it returns null.

Comment: @IdanShechter what do you mean with "items are out of bound"?

Comment: @IdanShechter This is well past the dated mark, but for future views:  _elementFromEndpoint()_ doesn't discriminate, it grabs all elements as you scroll, making unintended elements get the "middle" class in this case. Wrapping the _classList.add_ in an if statement is a quick solution. `if(element.hasAttribute('data-page')){ element.classList.add("middle");}`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this sometime later, building on @[Idan Schechter][1]'s response, I thought I would show the change that he found.  (Full credit to him).  I couldn't comment so am adding as a complete answer here:

```
    $(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){        
        // get the scroll position of the document + half the window height
        var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() / 2);
        var positions = [];

        // push each of the items we want to check against to an array with their position and selector
        $('.item').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            positions.push({position:$(this).offset().top, element: $(this)});
        });

        var getClosest = closest(positions,scrollTop);
        getClosest.addClass("active"); // the element closest to the middle of the screen
        console.log( getClosest.attr("data-page") );
    });

    // finds the nearest position (from an array of objects) to the specified number
    function closest(array, number) {
        var num = 0;
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(Math.abs(number - array[i].position) < Math.abs(number - array[num].position)){
                num = i;
            }
        }
        return array[num].element;
    }
});
```

The big change is to change the position in the main function to offset.  That was what helped the function do what I needed.