# Get element closest to the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get the element that is closest to the middle of the screen. Similar question has already been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564156/get-the-element-closer-to-the-middle-of-the-screen-in-jquery). This works great unless you have content in a container that is larger than the view port. In my scenario by default the content does not exceed the height of the viewport, but there is functionality to allow the user to add more input fields which can mean it goes beyond the viewport.

When you are viewing an element, it's supposed to stay in view (full opacity) until another element is more in view, at which point, the original will go to low opacity.

See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6rzuqknx/4/ - once you get half way through first element, it goes to low opacity. The two functions below are the functions I currently use to get the closest element:

```
// calculate what element is in middle of viewport
function closest(array, number) {
  var num = 0;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (Math.abs(number - array[i].position) < Math.abs(number - array[num].position)) {
      num = i;
    }
  }
  return array[num].element;
}

// get positions of all question divs
function getPositions() {
  var positions = [];

  $('.question').each(function() {
    // $(this).removeClass("showing");
    positions.push({
      position: $(this).position().top,
      element: $(this)
    });
  });

  return positions;
}
```

Apologies for the mess of my code, it's within a fairly big project and it wasn't the easiest snipping part of it.

Cheers guys

Comment: *"See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6rzuqknx/4/"* Please put your runnable examples **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Always be sure to reduce the example to a [mcve].

Comment: Would `document.elementFromPoint(document.offsetWidth / 2, document.offsetHeight / 2)` work?

Comment: @alex Thanks Alex! That worked - if you want to write an answer I'll mark as answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand from my comment, this should do it:

```
const centeredElement = document.elementFromPoint(
  document.body.offsetWidth / 2, document.body.offsetHeight / 2
);
```