# Getting the id of the element which is the closest to the centre of the users screen in pure JS

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the id of the element which is the closest to the center of the user's screen in pure JS?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564156/get-the-element-closer-to-the-middle-of-the-screen-in-jquery/38564630) JS code on another question but unfortunately, it just gets the parent's class and not the ID of the element?

The JS code:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  let x = window.innerWidth / 2;
  let y = window.innerHeight / 2;
  let element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  let page = element.getAttribute("data-page");
  document.querySelector(".middle") &&   document.querySelector(".middle").classList.remove("middle");
  element.classList.add("middle"); 
})
```

But this has a problem, when It's in the exact middle it puts the class on the parent, and if the items are out of bound, it returns null.

So how would I be able to get the closest possible value and not just the one which is exactly in the middle of the viewport?

HTML:

```
<ul id="posts">
<p id="1">1</p>
<p id="2">2</p>
<p id="3">3</p>
<p id="4">4</p>
<p id="5">5</p>
<p id="6">6</p>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you want to get the element which is closest to the centre of the viewport? I'm asking because maybe there is better way of achieving your desired result without too much JS calculations.

Comment: but WHY do you need the id which is closest to the centre of the viewport? WHAT do you want to do with it once you figured it out? Maybe you want to scroll to something? Or you wnat to highlight something? or...?

Comment: Perhaps you could give a more functional example? I mean, OK, I see the event listener. But what is the html you are working on?

Comment: Well it is an unordered list with several elements within.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here. You've already got the element that's at the center of the screen from `elementFromPoint`. You've also got the scroll position, and presumably you know the height of each item. That should be plenty to do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: It works

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    let x = (window.innerWidth) / 2 + window.scrollX;
    let y = (window.innerHeight) / 2 + window.scrollY;
    let minDist = 50000;
    let minDistElement = null;
    for (let i = 1; i < 7; i += 1) {
        let targetNode = document.getElementById(i);
        let centerX = targetNode.offsetLeft + targetNode.offsetWidth / 2;
        let centerY = targetNode.offsetTop + targetNode.offsetHeight / 2;
        let distance = Math.abs(x - centerX) + Math.abs(y - centerY)
        console.log('distance from ',i,distance)
        if (distance < minDist) {
            minDist = distance;
            minDistElement = targetNode
        }
    }
    console.log("most center element : " + minDistElement.id)

})
```

```css
p{
min-height:100px

}
```

```html
<ul id="posts">
<p id="1">1</p>
<p id="2">2</p>
<p id="3">3</p>
<p id="4">4</p>
<p id="5">5</p>
<p id="6">6</p>
</ul>
```